# Using Python to override Windows Common File Dialog (and other Open/Save File Dialog windows)

Tags: python, windows, dialog, save, intercept

I am trying to write a program that will control document naming and file system placement of assets into our server.  I have been writing it in Python and have had much luck thanks to everyone on here and the wealth of information on stackoverflow.

That being said, I can't find anything on the next step I am trying to take.  I optimally want my program to run instead of the Windows/Linux Common File Dialog method.  For example, when someone presses the "Save" button or "Open" button in a program, I would like my program to open up and be the way people find and save files.  I would be okay with it acting as an intermediate system (runs on save or open call, but then returns its info to the native dialog) but would like it to take over.  I was thinking I need to write a deamon program to listen for the appropriate call and intercept but am not sure.  Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance!

-Louis

Comment: It sounds like you want to override the file dialog in all applications.  Is that correct?

Comment: That's how I understand it. He wants to replace the default open-file dialog on windows/linux.

Comment: Exactly, I want to override the file dialog for all applications in both windows and linux.  Or at least have my program run when Open/Save/Save-As are called by any application.  My program is designed to provided a standard naming protocol and help guide the user to a desired location for the document they are creating or trying to find.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  Or if it can be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

Link the 'save as' and 'open' buttons to these; it worked perfectly for me:

```
def onOpen(self):
    ftypes = [('Python files', '*.py'), ('All files', '*')]
    dlg = Tkinter.FileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
    fl = dlg.show()

    if fl != '':
        text = self.readFile(fl)
        self.txt.insert(END, text)

def onSave_as(self):
     savefile = Tkinter.FileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode = 'w', defaultextension=".txte")
     self.parent.title("myTxtEditor")
     if savefile is None:
         return
     text2save = str(self.txt.get(1.0, END))
     savefile.write(text2save)
     savefile.close()
```